# Angular 2 & leaflet maps

Tags: angular, leaflet

I'm having trouble getting leaflet maps working in angular 2.  In notepad, I have wrote the following code to create a simple map:

```
<head>
    <title>Experiment maps</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="map" style="height: 400px; background: #919191;"></div>

<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([54.5833300, -5.9333300], 13);   

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
        {
        attribution: 'Tiles by <a href="http://mapc.org">MAPC</a>, Data by <a   

href="http://mass.gov/mgis">MassGIS</a>',
         maxZoom: 17,
         minZoom: 9
        }).addTo(map);
</script>

<h1>map</h1>

</body>
```

I have imported the same stylesheet and script into the index.html file in angular, however, when I load a component I just get a div placeholder of 400px with a red background, no map in any shape or form.  Am I referencing leaflet's css and script files incorrectly?

I have also tried adding `styleUrls: ['https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0-rc.3/dist/leaflet.css']` into the angular component itself, with no success.

Also, can you have 2 stylesheets referenced in the index.html, with with rel="stylesheet", like this:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.0-   rc.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
```

I have tried deleting my original style.css and just leaving leftlet's version.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I develop in typescript (angular 2), and I used the offical javascript leaflet docs.

you just need to install the leaflet directory with this line: 
`npm install leaflet` .

and add after the installation this import at your imports:

```
import L from "leaflet";
```

finally you can use leaflet the same as shown at [leaflet docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.1.0.html).
(with small changes look at google)

Good luck.

Comment: import * as L from 'leaflet' ; in the new syntax

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use leaflet the 'regular' way within a component this way.
You will have to load it into your project using npm for example (`npm install leaflet`).

Here is a nice tutorial on how to incorporate this into your Angular 2 application:
https://asymmetrik.com/ngx-leaflet-tutorial-angular-cli/